# How can I get CMake to remove a directory only if it is empty?

Tags: cmake

I see multiple options for deleting directories but they all act recursively

I.e.

```
 cmake -E rm -r mydir
```

Since this is part of an uninstall script (running at high privilege) it makes me nervous to to run what is effectively

```
 sudo rm -rf <some path that I might get wrong>
```

I want to only delete a directory that I know for sure is empty.

I saw there were two recurse flags for `cmake -E rm`, `-r` and `-R`, maybe they do different things? No they are synonyms for each other.

Comment: if you are not sure what the script will do it's always good to test before running it on PRO. In order to remove the exact empty folder `rmdir mydir` you can use `cmake -E rmdir mydir` which will remove the dir if it's empty

Comment: "_I saw there were two recurse flags for cmake -E rm, -r and -R, maybe they do different things? No they are synonyms for each other._" what is the point of stating that in your question post?

Comment: @RAI - i assume you mean -E remove_directory (there is no -E rmdir). That is deprecated. And it delets recursively and non empty dirs (like rm -r)

Comment: @user - i went off and read the source code of -E to see if there was anything I missed there.

Comment: @pm100 great. I did the same. and I still don't get why you consider that a necessary detail to include in your question post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `cmake -E rm` to remove only empty directories. If try to remove a directory without specifying `-r` or `-R`, you'll get "*Error removing directory "<directory path>" without recursive option.*". Even [`file(REMOVE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#remove) can't be used to remove empty directories. You can use a combination of [`if(IS_DIRECTORY)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#file-operations), [`file(GLOB)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob), [`if(STREQUAL)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#comparisons), and [`file(REMOVE_RECURSIVE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem):

```
if(IS_DIRECTORY)
  file(GLOB dir_to_rm_list "<path to dir_to_rm>/*")
  if("${dir_to_rm_list}" STREQUAL "")
    file(REMOVE_RECURSIVE "<path to dir_to_rm>")
  endif()
endif()
```

You can put that in a `function` if you want, and if you need to run it as a custom target or custom command, put it in its own `.cmake` file and run it with [`cmake -D... -P`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script).